# MVC3 Viewmodel and linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, ienumerable

In a web page I want to be able to return BlogCategoryName with the number of blogs in category. For example

BlogNameX(3)
BlogNameY(4)
....

I’m using the entity framework and have a blog category class

```
namespace emoCard.Domain.Entities
{
   public class BlogCategory
   {

     public BlogCategory()
     {
        this.Blogs = new List<Blog>();
     }

     public int BlogCategoryID { get; set; }
     public string BlogCategoryName { get; set; }
     public string BlogCategoryDescription { get; set; }
     public int BlogCategoryOrder { get; set; }

     public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I could setup a viewmodel along the lines of

```
namespace emoCard.WebUI.Models
{

  public class BlogCategoryViewModel
  {
    public IEnumerable<BlogCategory> BlogCategories { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And then have a controller that looks like

```
public PartialViewResult BlogCategories()
    {

        BlogCategoryViewModel viewModel = new BlogCategoryViewModel
        {
            BlogCategories = repository.BlogCategories.Include(b => b.Blogs)
        };

        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }
```

I can then count the number of blogs in each category in the view.

This works but I have a number of problems with this. These are:

- I need to pull back all the information (i.e. I don’t really need the blog information only the count).
- It doesn’t seem correct to calculate the count in the view.

I think I need to change my viewmodel so that I can populate the blog categories and number of blogs associated with each category and then create a linq query that categories and blog count but not all blog information. I think the new viewmodel should be along the lines of

```
  public BlogCategoryMenuItem(BlogCategory blogCategories, int numberOfBlogs)
  {
    BlogCategories = blogCategories;
    NumberOfBlogs = numberOfBlogs;

  }

public class BlogCategoryViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<BlogCategoryMenuItem> BlogCategoryMenuItem { get; set; }
}
```

I have two questions:
1.  Is this the best way to solve the problem I have?
2.  How do I populate this viewmodel object using linq?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my blog, I use a stored procedure to get this:

```
SELECT [Category].Name,
       [Category].DisplayName,
       COUNT(pc.PostId) AS PostCount
FROM   [Category]
       LEFT JOIN PostCategory pc
            ON  pc.CategoryId = [Category].Id
GROUP BY
       [Category].Name,
       [Category].DisplayName
```

And then, I map this in Entity Framework, which generate a "GetCategoryCountList_Result" class.

In my cshtml View:

```
@model List<EdiBlog.Core.Entities.GetCategoryCountList_Result>
...
@if (Model.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="@Url.Content("~/Category/List/" + @item.Name)">@item.DisplayName <span class="count uiSideNavCount fr">@item.PostCount</span></a>
                </li>
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Automapper it is designed to create view models from entities.  If you name the properties correctly it automatically does the mapping. Alternatively you can define mapping yourself.  Can find it here with some usage advice https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

The following article covers the basics pretty well http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/02/01/simplify-your-projections-with-automapper.aspx

You simply define a mapping between an entity and a viewmodel and then call map which can be as simple as:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerInfo>();
var CustomerInfo = Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerInfo>(customer);
```

Automapper attempts to match fields based on naming convention and then sets the values based on the value in the entity etc.

Comment: Thanks Graeme. My preference is this as I can easily add in unit testing and it keeps a better split between my data layer and business layer.

Comment: If you feel it is the best answer and it solves your problem you could accept it :)